# React passing useState as props gives me undefined?

Tags: reactjs, use-state, react-props

I don't understand what's happening on my App. I'm trying to make a simple pizza store where you can simply add products to cart. I'm using react router, and i've already initialized the cart dropdown (when you click on the cart icon, the cart dropdown appears) using useState. No problems so far.

Now I'm trying to set state with [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]); in App, to be able to pass down the state as props. I'm console logging the cartItems in App.js and I get an empty array.

Now I'm passing in the  the props like this  and when I'm console logging what I get in the navbar, I get undefined. Why is that happening?

App.Js code here:

```js
import Navbar from "./routes/Navbar";
import {useState} from 'react';
import Homepage from "./routes/Homepage";
import SignIn from "./routes/SignIn";
import Register from "./routes/Register";
import {Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Menu from "./routes/Menu";
import pizzas from '../src/data';

function App() {

  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);
  

  const onAdd = (product) => {
    const exist = cartItems.find(x => x.id === product.id);
    if(exist) {
      setCartItems(cartItems.map(x => x.id === product.id 
        ?
        {...exist, qty: exist.qty + 1}
        :
        x
        ))
    } else {
      setCartItems([...cartItems, {...product, qty: 1}]);
    }
  }

  return (
   <Routes>
     <Route  path='/' element={<Navbar onAdd={onAdd} cartItems={cartItems}/> }/>
     <Route index element={<Homepage /> }/>
     <Route path='/menu' element={<Menu pizzas={pizzas} onAdd={onAdd} /> }/>
     <Route path='/auth' element={<SignIn /> }/>
     <Route path='/register' element={<Register /> }/>
     
   </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and Navbar.jsx code here:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import LogoImg from '../assets/logo.png';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import CartIconComponent from '../components/CartIconComponent';
import CartDropdown from '../components/CartDropdown';

const Navbar = (props) => {

    const [cartOpen, setCartOpen] = useState(false);

    const {onAdd} = props;
    const {cartItems} = props;
    console.log(cartItems);
    

    const handleClick = () => {
        setCartOpen(!cartOpen);
    }
    
  return (
    <Container>
        <LogoContainer>
        <Link to='/'>
            <Logo src={LogoImg}/>
        </Link>
        </LogoContainer>
        
        <LinksContainer>
        <Link to='/menu'>
            OUR MENU
        </Link>
        <Link to='/auth'>
            SIGN IN
        </Link>
        <Link to='/register'>
            REGISTER
        </Link>
        <CartIconComponent 
        onPress={handleClick}
        cartOpen={cartOpen}
        
        
        />
        </LinksContainer>
        {cartOpen && <CartDropdown cartItems={cartItems} onAdd={onAdd}/>}
       
    </Container>
  )
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for you it has been a long time.

I had the same problem and found this: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/putting-props-to-use-state

Basically you need a 'key' prop in order to insert a prop as useState for React to think its legit

Hope it will help someone.